# Changing text of title and header in panorama/panoramaItem

Tags: windows-phone-7

Hy guys, i have a question, I have app that is in panorama, and on one item i have few radiobuttons, that represents some languages(it is a page where you can change language of app) is there any possibility, when i select one of that buttons and click ok button, to change text of panorama Title, panoramaItem Header?
for example, i did that in some other app that is ordinary wp app, and there is:

```
private void Ok_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(radiobutton1.ischecked==true)
    applicationTitle.text=myApp.Lang.SomeTitle; 
    ......
}
```

where i used resource file named Lang, etc.
I think something in this direction... Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, i didn't name my panorama/panoramaItem, when you name it you have access to that options, so if anyone ever need this, that should do... thanks anyway...